# Android MQTT and SSL

Tags: android, ssl, mqtt

I am trying to connect via SSL and certificate to have a solid and secure connection but apparently it is not as simple as it looks like.

Using python is 100% working and  can test the connecton by using these paramters

```
client.tls_set(ca_certs="x.pem", certfile="/y.pem.crt", keyfile="z.pem.key", cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED, tls_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2,ciphers=None)
client.tls_insecure_set(True)
```

I was applying different varian of code found on the internet and even on here and applying the SSLSocketFactory on my MqttConnectOptions.
Common errors were like "SSL path not found" ( yes I did check if the code was reading the file and it worked ), "Trust anchor for certification path not found." and so on....

I also had issue to parse the key file to PemParse due to be in the resources but with not much luck.

This one of the link I was following as well https://gist.github.com/sharonbn/4104301 but with no much success.
Just to "complicate things", my certificate are without password and most of the examples on the web are with.

**To recap:**

- I have x.pem, y-private.pem.key, z-certificate.pem.crt, u-public.pem.key
- With python works fine
- Android is not working or at least I am not able to.

In case it wasnt clean, I am after a piece of code that allows me to use the certificates above to add to my MqttConnectOptions and make a successfully connection to the server.

Comment: There isn't a question here.

Comment: the question is to help out to define the code that I can apply to MqttConnectOptions  by using the  certificates above.

Comment: Please read the doc on what a good question needs: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask